# jmap tool work for JVM 1.3 and older?

Tags: java, heap-memory, jmap

Can we use the jmap tool (version Java 1.4) to generate a heap dump file for an older jvm version? For example Java 1.3?
If it is not possible, is there a way to get a heap dump from the Java 1.3 JVM?

Comment: Since you are talking about an over ten year old *API* version but asking for a *product* feature you should name the exact product as there were more than one vendor and several updates of compatible JVMs.

Comment: @Holger it is statndard SUN JDK